# Is there a framework for dynamically generating a Swing GUI from a Pojo in Runtime?

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, pojo

My problem is, that I have simple Pojos or simply objects that contain data. These can vary and new types of these can be added during runtime.

So I need a Swing GUI to input text to them. Is there a framework that dynamically creates a Swing GUI from a POJO during runtime? Technically, it should be possible using reflection and/or annotations. However, I have found nothing on the web. Is there anything like this out there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.metawidget.org/

Metawidget is a 'smart User Interface widget' that populates itself, at runtime, with UI components to match the properties of your business objects.

Metawidget does this without introducing new technologies. It inspects your existing back-end architecture (such as JavaBeans, existing annotations, existing XML configuration files) and creates widgets native to your existing front-end framework (such as Swing, Java Server Faces, Struts, Android).